# Rails 3's "bundle install" is super fast (takes 1 second), but no Rails is there afterwards? (using rvm)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

I am using rvm, doing the following:

```
rvm install ree    <--- (Ruby Enterprise Edition), or this can be 1.8.7 or 1.9.2
rvm ree
rvm gemset create 'proj'
cd path/to/proj
bundle install
```

so Gemfile in that project says:

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.0'
```

and `bundle install` is super fast, reporting

```
Using rails (3.0.0)
```

but after that when I type

```
$ rails -v
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:779:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:214:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:1082:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails:18

$ which rails
/usr/bin/rails
```

so `bundle install` doesn't install the rails as a gem?
but if I type `script/rails -v` it shows it is 3.0.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is correct. `bundle install` won't install Rails as a gem in the conventional sense. Now to explain why.

When Bundler runs an install, it will install the gems a directory: `~/.bundle/<type-of-ruby>/<version>/gems`. This is different to the normal way of installing them to a system path. When a gem is installed at a system path, the executable is made available because that directory is within the load path. Now this is a **bad** thing, because you can only have one executable *per gem*. Have you got SomeGem v2 installed but want to use the generator from SomeGem v1? Too bad.

Bundler solves this problem by installing them into the afore-mentioned location and only requiring specific versions of the gems it needs (specified inside of `Gemfile`. By running simply `rails`, you're trying to run the *system* executable (as in one provided by doing `gem install rails`) rather than the Bundler one (provided by doing `bundle install` for a Rails project).

To run the one that Bundler installs you must run it like this `bundle exec rails` within a directory that contains a `Gemfile` that specifies any version of Rails. Bundler will load a specific version of Rails and you should now be able to run them side-by-side with the only tradeoff being the `bundle exec` prefix to commands.

Personally I've aliased this to `be` and two characters before some commands is a worthwhile tradeoff to avoiding The Seventh Circle of Gem Conflict Hell in my opinion.

Comment: now, but every guide I saw (Official Rails guide, Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl) says the way to use Rails is just "rails generate", and presumably, people need to `gem install rails` before they can have a project (or at least 1 person in the team), so that he can have `script/rails` and `bundle exec rails`.  So this 1 person may be using SomeGem v1 and SomeGem v2 at the same time any way (Gem being Rails in this case).  I think maybe a documentation can explain the 3 ways of invoking Rails...

Comment: @Jian Lin: Yes, to initially generate a Rails application you need to have the Rails gem installed without using Bundler. To run a Rails project however you only need it installed as a bundled gem.

Answer (score 0):

your procedure seems correct (be sure to use the newly created gemset too, verify by `rvm info`, do `rvm ree@proj` if it doesn't say gemset: 'proj' ), so I'll stick my head out and try a suggestion. Btw, rails installs perfectly with bundler.

I've been struggling with wierd behaviour system gems vs local gems, as have a lot of bundler users, including Yehuda Katz, leading to this comprehensive post [A Tale of Abort Traps](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/08/24/a-tale-of-abort-traps-or-always-question-your-assumptions/)

In short, if you run bundle install *before* you have the bundler gem (getting the "standard" gem not found error), then do *gem install bundler*, followed by another bundle install, the bundler gem has been install to your *system, not rvm*.

**Solution**: Delete .bundle, (and do gem uninstall bundler?). Then I would open a new term, do rvm ree@proj, and gem install bundler prior to bundle install.

Yehuda says in the post that it is fixed in new bundler versions, but I experienced this just a few days ago (bundler 1.0.0). Hope I brought more help than confusion to the table :)