# Rails 2.3.8: Could not find RubyGem bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm trying to set up a development environment for a legacy Rails 2.3.8 project.  I have rails successfully installed, have cloned the git repository, and now am trying to run bundle.

Could not find RubyGem bundler (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:214:in `activate'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1082:in`gem'
    from /home/[clientsite]/ruby/gems/bin/bundle:18

(where [clientsite] is not the actual directory name.)

Also:
which ruby:
/usr/bin/ruby
which rails:
/usr/bin/rails
which bundle:
/home/ankasa/ruby/gems/bin/bundle

When I try to run rake, I get this:
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- rdoc/task

I assume this is because I can't run bundle.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662986/rails-3s-bundle-install-is-super-fast-takes-1-second-but-no-rails-is-there perhaps this will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Rails 2.3.8 project does not use bundle to manage its dependencies. There's no Gemfile. The required gems are listed in config/environment.rb.

To fix the problem with rake, you need to install rdoc gem, and edit Rakefile file:

```
#require 'rake/rdoctask'
require 'rdoc/task'
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the Gemfile, I've only used Rails 3.